# What's the difference between Gaussian and Bernoulli?

Tags: distributions

Starting from this sentence:

> The *trait theory* considers for example introversion and extroversion
>   as two extremes of a single continuous line: the population will be
>   distributed in a **Gaussian** on the line; *type theory* instead consider
>   introversion and extroversion as two poles of attraction: the
>   distribution will be a **Bernoulli** distribution.

I've studied Analysis at the university, but my mind sees a lot of symbols like this: ???

Can you help me to understand which is the difference between the two functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trait theory associates a real number to the level of introversion / extroversion of an individual, with total introversion corresponding to, say, $-\infty$, and total extroversion to $\infty$, depending on the adopted conventions. In this theory, introversion / extroversion is considered as varying continuously among individuals. Hence, uncertainty about introversion / extroversion of a particular individual can be modeled as a continuous [random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable), and one possible convenient model is a random variable with [Gaussian distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), also known as Normal distribution.

Jung's type theory considers that each individual is either introverted or extroverted. That is, introversion / extroversion of an individual is a dichotomic variable, whose uncertainty can be mathematically described by a random variable with [Bernoulli distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution), which is a discrete random variable assuming only values $0$ (say, introverted) and $1$ (extroverted).